# Tracking inventory on Monogrammed Products

Tags: shopify

So I have wallet that can be monogrammed. In my admin I have 1 product with 2 variants – Not Monogrammed and Monogrammed. The monogrammed product costs $20 more.

My issue is that I have 10 wallets total, but when I have the variants separated like this I have to add inventory for each one.

I need to be able to track these inventories together. I have 10 total wallets, if one is monogrammed I still only have 9 total wallets. Not 10 non-monogrammed and 9 monogrammed left as it would handle it by default.

Is there a way to remedy this? Perhaps with an app? Or perhaps with a different setup, maybe with line item properties? I've found that those don't effect price though.

Answer (score 2):

I found an app that should do what you need, but it costs $7.95/month.

[Shopify Assistant](http://www.shopifyassistant.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Your monogrammed variant can be set up with inventory_policy:'continue' and keep 0 in stock. Let the non-monogrammed variant track the stock. 
inventory polity :continue lets customers purchase the monogrammed item.

Then you would probably need to modify your page template so that no purchases can be made if the first variant is out of stock.

Comment: I must be missing something, because how would this work if they ordered a Monogrammed wallet? How would it deduct inventory from the non-monogrammed variant?

Comment: It won't. Updating non-monogrammed inventory would have to be part of your process. This can be an app or a private app or just part of a manual checklist -- which one to use depends on your volume.

Comment: This is the part I'm looking for with my question. Let's say "manual" updating of my inventory is out of the question.

Comment: Then you are looking at an app to manage this. A simple web hook app could be created on your own server or perhaps Heroku. Then you'd install web hook that would receive the order notice and update the non-mono inventory when an monogrammed inventory order is received. If you run close to stockout then the webhook could keep the monogrammed inventory in Shopify in sync with the non-mono inventory and you'd disallow orders when you are out of inventory.  The app would also provide opportunity to disable the item if you reach a safety stock level (whether this is useful depends on volume)